# PyCharm IDE organized venv directory inside the project directory. What about git?

Tags: git

Newest PyCharm IDE creates venv inside the project dir.

Like this:

```
TestProject
   |
    \venv
```

I usually launched git init inside TestProject. But now the venv is here. I don't know how to organize git repository. 
For example, should I:
1) Move venv from the project dir to some other place?
2) Include venv into my git repository and even send it to the remote repository?
    TestProject
       |
        \venv
         .git
       |
       \TestProject
             |
             \test.py

3) Organize another level

```
TestProject
   |
    \venv
   |
   \TestProject
         |
         \test.py
          .git
```

Could you share your best practive with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice here is to setup your git root in the project root and add the `venv` directory to `.gitignore`. This way, the git root will be where it should be, and the virtual environment data won't be tracked by git and pushed to the remote.

I would also recommend recreating the virtual environment in a directory named `.env` or `.venv` (note the leading dot) inside the project root.

Comment: Mijhail, why do you want to hide venv directory? Aren't you used to have a look whether an installed librery is really present in venv?

Comment: Well, 1) it's still very easy to look inside the venv directory (you can `cd` into it in a shell), 2) PyCharm shows it in the tree regardless of whether it is hidden, and 3) a better way to look if a package is or isn't installed is using `pip list` after activating the venv.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn sorry, I'm a beginner. What do you mean with 'recreating the virtual enviroment'? Should I find some option in Pycharm to make it create a env called `.venv` instead of `venv` or I have to delete manually venv and create manually .venv and then associate it to Pycharm? thank you

Comment: @fabio PyCharm allows you to create a virtual environment in any location, see the help page [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html). You can also delete your old virtualenv from PyCharm there, but AFAIK this won't delete it from disk, you'll have to remove the directory manually.